# Rails controller rendering last template of iteration for all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I had controller tests that check that the right template is rendered for varying status codes. They worked.

I am trying to refactor the tests using iteration as follows:

```
context 'renders multiple views based on status code' do
  VIEW_MAP = {
    404 => 'not_found', 500 => 'server_response', 402 => 'client_response'
  }

  VIEW_MAP.each do |status_code, view|
    retrieve_deal(status_code)
    it 'renders the #{view} template for status code #{status_code}' do
      get :show, params: { id: 'id' }
      expect(response).to render_template(view)
    end
  end
end
```

where `retrieve_deal` method mocks an API call with a status code, and sends the response to the controller.

However, the last template (`'client_response'`) is rendered for all the tests. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: can you add `retrieve_deal` method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think each iteration needs to be in a `context`, and:

```
retrieve_deal(status_code)
```

needs to be in something like `before`.

Comment: Thanks that did it.  As you said I had to move the context within the iteration.  Thanks for the fast response sawa!